# Compatibility issues

Tags: powerbi, version

I'm experiencing problems between versions of Power BI. I have created a report from my computer, which seems to have the latest updated version of the program, but when I wanted to take my report to my other computer, it says that the version of Power BI that created it is newer and can not open it.

Is there any way to indicate from the creator computer, that the report makes it compatible with previous versions? The problem is that in the computer where I want to open my Power BI can not download the latest version of the program.

Thanks!

2.70 where it works, 2.41 where it doesn't work.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible, microsoft brings out frequent new versions of desktop to give us new functionality. The concept is not to us the desktop to show/use reports, only to develop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. The only way you can determine what version is to go into the options and check it there. If you are not using a feature in the new version then Power BI mostly retains backwards compatibility.